# Html table not displaying correctly

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to display a table with information about inmates.

I am using Flask and Jinja to pass in the data from my python file to the html document:

```
headings = ("First", "Last", "Court Date", "Bond Amount", "Bond Paid", "Charges")
data = (
        ("Carl", "Johnson", "12/12/2023", 1200, 900, "Murder"),
        ("Joe", "Lewis", "10/22/2023", 2000, 890, "Theft"),
        ("Jarod", "Green", "11/29/2023", 1900, 700, "Robbery") 
    )

@views.route("/info/")
def info():
    return render_template("info.html", headings=headings, data=data)
```

My html doc:

```
<table>
 <tr>
 {%for header in headings%}
   <th>{{ header }}</th>
 {%endfor%}
 </tr>
 {%for row in data%}
 <tr>
 {%for cell in row%}
   <td>{{ cell }}</td>
 {%endfor%}
 </tr>
 {%endfor%}
</table>
```

My html doc displays the following on the page:

{%for header in headings%} {%endfor%} {%for row in data%} {%for cell in row%} {%endfor%} {%endfor%}
{{ header }}
{{ cell }}

It doesn't show a table at all, just the jinja code.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your question and it is working on my side here is the link to the repository where you can find all the files I used, https://github.com/HarunMbaabu/StackOveflow-Answered-Question/tree/main/flask_table_not_displaying_correctly .

Make sure that you have connected the HTML and the Flask server file well, it is advisable to use the templates folder. Below is my code:

Python file:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

views = Flask(__name__) 


#Route Example
@views.route("/")
def index():
    # Define the base URL
    base_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
    
    # Create the link URL
    info_url = f"{base_url}/info"

    return f"Test your table info endpoint here your endpoint at <a href='{info_url}'>{info_url}</a>"

#Relevant Code for your question start here
headings = ("First", "Last", "Court Date", "Bond Amount", "Bond Paid", "Charges")

data = (
        ("Carl", "Johnson", "12/12/2023", 1200, 900, "Murder"),
        ("Joe", "Lewis", "10/22/2023", 2000, 890, "Theft"),
        ("Jarod", "Green", "11/29/2023", 1900, 700, "Robbery") 
    )


@views.route("/info/")
def info():
    return render_template("info.html", headings=headings, data=data)
#Relevant code for your question ends here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    views.run(debug=True)
```

templates/info.html file:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    {%for header in headings%}
      <th>{{ header }}</th>
    {%endfor%}
    </tr>
    {%for row in data%}
    <tr>
    {%for cell in row%}
      <td>{{ cell }}</td>
    {%endfor%}
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
   </table>
```

Output:
[image]